# Selenium - elements not captued

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

As i was trying selenium through Python, I am unable to extract the titles from the yahoo finance page.

Below is the code that I am working with:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.finance.yahoo.com')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Industries']").click()

element_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@data-test='secnav-list']//child::a")

#element_list remains empty - not sure why
for i in element_list:
    print(i.get_attribute('title'))
```

I was hoping to get 9 titles (Financial,Healthcare,Services,Utilities,Industrial Goods,Basic Materials,Conglomerates,Consumer Goods,Technology). However the list of elements shows empty list and hence the for loop does not get executed.

I tried the xpath in chrome inspect. I also tried in other xpath-practice-tools online, and it seems to return all the elements correctly. Not sure why it does not work in the program.

One other thing I tried is to give a filter condition in xpath like

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@data-test='secnav-list']//child::a[@title='Healthcare']")
```

This one returns the element correctly in the program.

Could anyone please help me understand what I am missing here? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to w*ait for the menu to show up* [explicitly with `WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.finance.yahoo.com')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Industries']").click()

# wait for menu to show up
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
company_menu = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-test=secnav-list]")))

titles = company_menu.find_elements_by_css_selector("li > a")
for title in titles:
    print(title.get_attribute('title'))
```

Prints:

```
Financial
Healthcare
Services
Utilities
Industrial Goods
Basic Materials
Conglomerates
Consumer Goods
Technology
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the titles from the yahoo finance page you don't need to `click()` and a simple *Mouse Hover* does the job inducing [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjuction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
  driver.get("http://www.finance.yahoo.com")
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Industries")))).perform()
  sub_menus = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div>ul li>a[href*='/sector/']")))
  for sub_menu in sub_menus:
      print(sub_menu.text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Financial
  Healthcare
  Services
  Utilities
  Industrial Goods
  Basic Materials
  Conglomerates
  Consumer Goods
  Technology
  ```